# Amazon Web Service Signature issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, web-services

I am trying to fetch product related data from Amazon Product API using this URL mentioned here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html

Item Lookup URL:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_Access_Key_ID]&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=B00008OE6I&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

I have entered required details/parameters in URL but I am unable to understand where to get this Signature from or how to generate this signature? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/HMACAuth_ItemsRequired.html _A signature is created by using the request type, domain, the URI, and a sorted string of every parameter in the request (except the Signature parameter itself) with the following format <parameter>=<value>&. Once properly formatted, you create a base64-encoded HMAC_SHA256 signature using your AWS secret key._

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way would be using one of AWS SDKs. You can find the full list here: https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

When you use the SDK you just supply your access key and secret key. The libraries handle preparing the signature.

Comment: I have used AWS SDK but that only returns product details that you yourself have added. While in my case I want to access details of all public products that are on amazon. I need an API or something that can return me product details

Comment: If you can already use the API then I don't see how it is related to signature.

Comment: See I want an API to fetch public products on Amazon. This AWS SDK basically is not helping me much. It helps me fetch S3 related stuff that I have uploaded but that is not what I am looking for.

I need an API that can fetch product and their details something like this:

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dappliances&field-keywords=television

Now the products listed over here. These are ones that I need through an API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no point in doing this by yourself in Ruby, once it has a SDK, but an explanation about signature process may be useful for some people.

Signature is the way AWS authenticates API requests. It is passed as a query string parameter on your HTTP request and is validated against your own request content and you credentials on server-side.

There are 2 versions of it: 2 and 4, explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html). Version 2 is not supported on newer regions (China and Frankfurt).

In version 2, which I'm more familiar with, the signature is generated based on a string with this format:

```
HTTPVerb + "\n" + ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase + "\n" + HTTPRequestURI
+ "\n" + CanonicalizedQueryString
```

The *CanonicalizedQueryString* is your query string, with parameters sorted (UTF-8 byte order) by paramater names and with parameter values url-encoded.

Then you calculate an *HMAC* of that string, using your *AWS secret key*, and *SHA256* or *SHA1* as the hash algorithm (depending on which one you have specified on query string parameter *SignatureMethod*), and encode it to base64. The result of all this will be the value of the *Signature* parameter.

I will try to walk you through a *CloudWatch* request, generated manually with bash tools.

Let's say you want to list you *CloudWatch* metrics. The request (without the signature) would be like the following.

```
http://monitoring.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=AVUKYAMNIIGWALNMA6IG&Action=ListMetrics&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-08-20T22%3A40%3A00.000Z&Version=2010-08-01
```

So, your string to sign would be:

```
GET
monitoring.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=AVUKYAMNIIGWALNMA6IG&Action=ListMetrics&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-08-20T22%3A40%3A00.000Z&Version=2010-08-01
```

Well, let's put it in a variable and do all the magic (hmac + base64)

```
#!/bin/bash

# your secret key
key='ry+SyjvXLvi4lYie/QfZYnxYOBQDggf01DTUxFSK'

# using 'read' to assign the signing string
# to a variable for readability reasons
read -r -d '' payload <<EOF
GET
monitoring.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=AVUKYAMNIIGWALNMA6IG\
&Action=ListMetrics\
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1\
&SignatureVersion=2&\
Timestamp=2015-08-20T22%3A40%3A00.000Z\
&Version=2010-08-01
EOF

echo -n "$payload" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $key -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Then, after all this, you will end up with something like this:

***xrIYF8wO0C8YOQgcdpq6MoJpBWzXEWxuTBAAoqYoGWM=***

This is your signature, and finally, you just need to url-encoded it and append it to your request as one more query-string parameter.

***&Signature=xrIYF8wO0C8YOQgcdpq6MoJpBWzXEWxuTBAAoqYoGWM%3D***

Hopefully, if you did everything correctly (putting the sign string together, generating the hash and encoding it), your request will be accepted and, if you have enough permission, executed.

So, as you can see, it's something not worth to do by yourself. Use the SDK. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys for your response. But I have finally figured out my problem and my solution was in this gem:

```
https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs
```

This is what I was actually looking for and it finally helped me achieve what I was trying to. Posting it over here so people can find a better solution.